# Integration of pyjamas and tornado

Tags: python, tornado, pyjamas

Is it possible to write an application using the `pyjamas` widgets, together with the `tornado` server model? What I have in mind is to provide a desktop-like frontend for my web application with `pyjamas`, and do server side logic with tornado.

Specifically, I want to trigger events in the web application generated in the server side, and be able to display those events using the `pyjamas` widgets.

Does somebody have a working example of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The route I have chosen is to combine pyjs (old pyjamas) with web2py, via JSONRPC. So far it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Some tornado references on the old pyjamas list, i'm not familiar with it though:
http://groups.google.com/group/pyjamas-dev/search?group=pyjamas-dev&q=tornado&qt_g=Search+in+this+group